# id() function in Python

Tags: python

In the following code:

```
L = [1,2,3]
addr1 = id(L)
L = L + [4,5]
addr2 = id(L)
L = [1,2,3]
addr3 = id(L)
L += [4,5]
addr4 = id(L)
print addr1 == addr2
print addr3 == addr4
```

The answer is `False`, `True`, but why?

I thought the `L += [4,5]` is just the short hand for `L = L +[4,5]`.

Comment: You should use `==` in your comparisons, not `=`. Is that a copying error?

Comment: Thank you, I missed the "=".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x += y` is not exactly equivalent to `x = x + y` when `x` is a list. When it's a list, `+=` performs an in-place modification to the list rather than creating a new list with the concatenation. But `+` always creates a new list.

Answer (score 3):

Objects can implement the `__iadd__` special method, which means "in-place add".

Lists implement this.

You can do this with your own objects, and either choose to return the original object or a new one.